# InitializationFunction for TemplateObject

Tags: expression-manipulation, hold, templates

**Shortly**, I want something like this to work:

```
 template = TemplateObject[
   ...
   RowBox[{"TemplateSlot", "[", "\"planet\"", "]"}]  (*valid boxes*)
   ...
 ] 

 template @ <|"planet" -> "Mars"|>
```

> ```
> "Mars" (*expression*)
> ```

While `template` should contain `RawBox[...]` information which I can extract later.

**The problem** is that `Inserting/CombinerFunction` are not enough since they work, more or less like:

```
CombinerFunction[template @@ (InsertingFunction /@ args)]
```

While I need:

```
CombinerFunction[ToExpression[template] @@ (InsertingFunction /@ args)]
```

**Details and requirements**:

As an answer I want an expression where the template content (here boxes) is supplied to an `InitializationFunction` (here `ToExpression`) just before it is filled by e.g. `TemplateApply.

I can't use custom `MyTemplateObject` because this template may be somewhere deep and I want it to be activated by the very outer `TemplateApply` that may come out of the blue. So too deep for upvalues and I would like not to make custom `MyTemplateApply`.

**Summing up:**

```
test = Grid[{{1, yourAnswer[RowBox[...]]}}];

TemplateApply[test, <|"planet" -> "Mars"|>]
```

> 1 Mars

But I still want to be able to extract original boxes from `test`.

Another use case can be to have a string template in its raw form because by default ``` StringTemplate["``<*1*>"] ``` evaluates to `TemplateObject[{TemplateSlot[1], "", TemplateExpression[1]}, 
 InsertionFunction -> TextString, CombinerFunction -> StringJoin]`

I have a solution but I feel like I missed something basic so I will hold on with posting it to not bias others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **the idiom** I use:

```
TemplateWith[
  "a" -> TemplateExpression @ initializationFunction @ rawTemplate
, TemplateSlot["a"]
]
```

For **OP's example**:

```
template =  TemplateWith[
  "$$this$$" -> TemplateExpression @ ToExpression @ RowBox[{"TemplateSlot", "[", "\"planet\"", "]"}]
, TemplateSlot["$$this$$"] (* "a" would not be very unique*)
];


TemplateApply[template, <|"planet" -> "Mars"|>]
```

> ```
> "Mars"
> ```

And I have **access to the raw template** too:

```
template[[1, 2, 1, 1]] (*or with pattern matching*)
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"TemplateSlot", "[", "\"planet\"", "]"}]
> ```

And **a  more secure version** in case we want to prevent initialized template from evaluation:

```
rawTemplate = RowBox[
  {"ToCharacterCode", "@", RowBox[{"TemplateSlot", "@", "\"\<planet\>\""}]}
];

template = TemplateObject[
  TemplateWith[
    "$$this$$" -> TemplateExpression @ MakeExpression @ rawTemplate
  , TemplateSlot["$$this$$"]
  ]
, CombinerFunction -> ReleaseHold
]

TemplateApply[template, <|"planet" -> "Mars"|>]
```

> ```
> {77, 97, 114, 115}
> ```

```
template[[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"ToCharacterCode", "@", RowBox[{"TemplateSlot", "@", "\"planet\""}]}]
> ```